# Admob ad request always return code 3

Tags: android, admob

[image]

I implement Admob in one of my android application. First time it has a banner add bellow of my application. But after adding banner ad in RecylearView after 8 items then problem occurs. 90% cases it returns response code 3.

Maximum time it showing me:

> I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
>   W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Here response code: 3 means ***The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.***  But other apps showing ads frequently in same device.

Notes:

- It showing demo ad when i test in TestDevice
- Problem occurring only non test devices
- Rare cases it successfully return ad.

Can anyone please help me to recover from this issue.Is there any issue in my ad_unit or adMob?

Comment: looks like problem with AdSize, try setting up all correct ad sizes . refer to this link https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177203#define

Comment: you have Google or Firebase dependencies?