# Admob Ads not showing up: Error Code 3 even after two weeks

Tags: java, android, admob

I have created some banner and interstitial ads on AdMob and implemented them in my android studio project. But the live ads aren't showing up in the release as well as debug version. When I set any device as a test device, then the test ads load on that device. 
I followed the advice given on some StackOverflow answers and waited for two weeks, but still, the problem persists. Some say that the ads will not be shown if your app is not added to the play store. Is it true?

I have followed the advice given in below questions:

[failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

[Admob No fill from ad server - failed to load ad: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610383/admob-no-fill-from-ad-server-failed-to-load-ad-3)

[Admob ad request always return code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757145/admob-ad-request-always-return-code-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 weeks doesn't matter here. My AdMob ads didn't work even for 4 weeks but after I uploaded the app to the play store, Everything seemed fine.

Anyways, this also requires the inventory to load return an ad. If you app was newly registered, then you should wait for enough ad requests. For me, It worked after around 5k requests.

For the ad requests, You can use a trick though I don't recommend it. For time being(while testing the app) you can add a `ScheduledExecuterService` and request ad multiple times but load them after specific intervals. This may increase chances of returning real ads.