# Cannot show test ads on android application (Admob)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

Whenever I run the app with test ads, I run into the following error-

```
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

I have followed the instructions from Admob closely for implementing banner and interstitial ads.

Also, I am not using a new account. My Admob account is over 2 years old and I have ads working perfectly fine in another app (I implemented ads in that application only last week).

Note that I had already created the ad units for this current application a while back, and only today decided the include ads in it. I have tried to create new ad units and tested using the test ad unit IDs but even the test ads do not load and give the above error.

On all the questions I have seen on this topic, test ads work but real ads don't whereas that is not the case for me. Both types of ads do not load.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to get the ads to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and looked through tons of stackoverflow questions but couldn't find an answer that matches me.

For me, if you log into Admob, you have to add an "app-ads.txt" file which then allows for the ads to be sent.

For reference, here is a short tutorial:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en

If you don't want to create an entire website, just use a free website hosting device. It doesn't matter if the name has like 20 numbers in it, you just need a working one.

Comment: I'll try this, but I have another app for which I put ads only last week and I did not have go through this step. Still, the ads show up just fine.

Comment: Hey, I have done the above steps. But still, ads do not show on my app. I still get the same error when I run test ads as well. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: hey, I am facing same issue in one of my App. Even on test ids provided by Google, I am getting this error. "adsLog: No ad config."  But when I change package name than it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your fault, when you see "I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3"

It means: "The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory."

I am used to always see "test ads" many times.
But, recently (~ 1 week ago) I kept seeing this message on "test ads".
I was quite curious about it, but it is no problem. This is just temporary.
Later it should work again.

See here for further references:

[failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

[Admob ad request always return code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757145/admob-ad-request-always-return-code-3/52165214#52165214)

Comment: But shouldn't the 'ad inventory' only affect my real ads not the test ads? As I'm using the test ad unit IDs?

Comment: Hey, it's been over a week yet there is no change. I still get the same error.

Comment: "My Admob account is over 2 years old and I have ads working perfectly fine in another app" --> ok, then it looks like,it is your implementation. Check, if app package name does not already exist in Google Play. Try with smartphone AND emulator. Generate a new ads id in your Google account. Find out the difference between working and non-working app. If nothing helps, send Feedback in Admob ...